# gcc include header and get output after preprocessing

Tags: c, gcc, include, preprocessor

I want the preprocessed output of a .c file, but I also want to include a header file without the macro "include..." in the .c file. Usually, you add the -I option for including a directory where headers are.
But if I want to combine -I and -E, gcc does't seem to include my header files in the specified directory.
My command:

```
gcc -E -I/externDefines myFirmware.c > myFirmware.preprocessed
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: You're probably looking for the [`-include <path>`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-include) flag.

Comment: " but I also want to include a header file without the macro "include...""  It's not a macro, it's an include. And the correct way to include files in C. If you don't want to use it for whatever reason (building a unit test etc) then consider wrapping the file you are testing inside another file that contains the relevant include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-I` does not mean “Include the header files from the given directory in the compilation.” It means “When searching for a file requested with `#include`, look for the file in the given directory.”

GCC has a command-line switch, `-include file` that will include a file in the compilation. However, it includes a single file, so you must list each file you want included; it will not automatically include all header files in a single directory. The command-line shell you are using may have features that help generate a list of `-include` switches with the file names.

A portable way to include a header file `X.h` while compiling `Y.c` without changing `Y.c` would be to create an auxiliary file containing:

```
#include "X.h"
#include "Y.c"
```

and then compile that instead of `Y.c`.